# pyautogui position return the same value always

Tags: pyautogui

I am having trouble with Pyautogui on Fedora 31.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.FAILSAFE= False
while True:
    print(pyautogui.position())
```

The error is that it does not matter where I move my mouse, in what windows or what screen. It always give me the same position:

```
Point(x=39, y=39)
...
Point(x=39, y=39)
Point(x=39, y=39)
```

Someone Knows? , I think that it could be a problem of packages, especifically python3-tkinter. though I have it (El paquete python3-tkinter-3.7.6-2.fc31.x86_64 ya está instalado.)
In Windows 10 it works perfect, but in Fedora 31 does not.

Greetings